# ANTLR: something wrong with list of tokens

Tags: antlr

Try `(honor+=NAME|honor+=DIGIT)+` and then `$honor` is a list of tokens.

I took out list of `$honor`

```
for(int r = 0; r < list_honor.size(); r++) 
  honorstr = honorstr + list_honor.get(r).text;
```

input: `test`

output: `[@752,2539:2585='test',<6>,19:11]`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the list is initialized in both alternatives:

```
rule
 : ( honor+=NAME  /* alternatvie 1 */
   | honor+=DIGIT /* alternatvie 2 */
   )+
 ;
```

Try something like this:

```
rule
 : honor+=(NAME | DIGIT)+ 
 ;
```

or if that doesn't work, something like this:

```
rule
 : honor+=sub_rule+
 ;

sub_rule
 : NAME
 | DIGIT 
 ;
```